# can I use updateTextInput() within shiny modules?

Tags: r, module, shiny, textinput

I have written a fairly straight forward module, consisting of a textInput on the client and a server function that updates the value of that textInput. To accomplish this, I call updateTextInput() in the server function. However, the textInput on the client is NOT updated.

What should I do to have my module server function update the textInput on the client?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

global.R with module definition

```
# Client side. 
specifyInput <- function(id, points){  
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(textInput(ns('points'), label='Total', value=points))
}

# Server side. 
specify <- function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    observe({
        new.value = 2 * as.numeric(input$points)
        #this line does not seem to work
        updateTextInput(session, ns('points'), value = new.value)
    })

    # create dataframe with entered value
    df <- reactive(data.frame(points = as.numeric(input$points)))

    # return the dataframe
    return(df())
}
```

ui.R

```
    specifyInput("ttlEntry", 10)
```

server.R

```
        function(input, output, session){
          test <- reactive(callModule(specify, "ttlEntry"))

          #somewhere in the code, call test()
        }
```

In reality, I want to attach a .5 behind the entered value when the user enters a period, for example if user enters "10." then the textInput is updated to display "10.5" 
However for testing purposes, I have changed that code to new.value = 2 * ...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things to note, all connected to the module server component:

1. I don't think you need the `ns <- session$ns` - I think this is reserved for using renderUI within modules (see [this article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)).
2. You don't need the to wrap the inputId in `ns()` within the module server - so  `ns('points')` should be changed to just `'points'`.
3. You shouldn't return `df()`, rather return just `df` without the parentheses.

Once you have made those changes, the app works, but note that there is a feedback loop created, so the entered value keeps doubling continuously. You would need to rework your code logic some more just to double what is entered once (or add a .5 as you describe) and leave it at that.

A working single file app version is posted below:

```
# Client side. 
specifyInput <- function(id, points){  
  ns <- NS(id)
  textInput(ns('points'), label = 'Total', value = points)
}

# Server side. 
specify <- function(input, output, session, ...){

  observe({
    new.value = 2 * as.numeric(input$points)
    updateTextInput(session, 'points', value = new.value)
  })

  # create dataframe with entered value
  df <- reactive(data.frame(points = as.numeric(input$points)))

  # return the dataframe
  return(df)
}

# ui
ui <- specifyInput("ttlEntry", 10)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session){
  test <- callModule(specify, "ttlEntry")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```